# A module to find linkable content

Tags: search

I am looking for a module that finds related pages for the purpose of linking them internally. For example, we have two pages, both have the name "Kill Bill" in their content, but they are not linked. The module would put the similar content to attention so that the editor can link the two pages. Or something similar to this.

I could implement Solr but it's not the preferred option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using the [Remove Duplicates](https://www.drupal.org/project/remove_duplicates) module.

Don't bother about the name of the module. you can use it as following way.

This module helps the administrator to easily find out the nodes according to one of the node fields.

So you can easily find out the same content pages and like those.